# In SSMS, display DateTimeOffset value in local timezone

Tags: sql-server, timezone, ssms, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

Isn't there a way to configure Sql Server Management Studio to, in query results, display the value of a `DateTimeOffset` column in the client's local timezone, instead of UTC?

Example: I'm in timezone +02:00. A value is stored as `2016-07-27 22:00:00.0000000 +00:00`. Currently, this value is displayed as such in query results. I want it to be displayed (formatted) as `2016-07-28 00:00:00.0000000 +02:00` when executing this query on SSMS on my machine.

Currently I'm manually using something like `SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, <DateColumn>), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))` which is obviously very cumbersome.

If I'm not mistaken, in Oracle the NLS parameters on session level could be used for this. Is there something similar in Sql Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither SQL Server nor SSMS have any ability to work with the concept of a "session time zone" (like Oracle, MySql, etc. do).

Also, it wouldn't make sense to automatically convert the offset anyway, as the offset is actually part of the stored `datetimeoffset` value.

If you're using SQL Server 2016, or Azure SQL Database, you can use the new [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx) statement, as in:

```
SELECT yourdto AT TIME ZONE @thetimezoneid
```

Otherwise, consider using my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project.

Neither of which can give you the system's time zone ID.  You must know which time zone you want to work with.

Comment: If the offset is stored as part of the value in the column, is it possible to store the local time rather than the zulu time?

Comment: You mean for `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server?  Yes - it stores the local time and the time zone offset for that local time.  However, it builds _indexes_ based on UTC equivalents.  The result is that queries based on `datetimeoffset` parameters will match the index just fine, but queries based on the local `date` part of the field value will end up doing a table scan.  Solution to that is to convert start-of-day and end-of-day to UTC before querying, or to keep a separate `date` column.