# In SSMS, apply AT TIME ZONE to all DateTimeOffset columns in query?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

For an ad-hoc query in SSMS, is it possible to specify AT TIME ZONE to be applied to all DateTimeOffset columns in the query?  Sometimes for diagnostic purposes it's easy to pop into SSMS and do a "select *" query to look at the data, but if the DateTimeOffset values are all in different time zones it's hard to convert between them for mental comparisons.

I've already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655186/in-ssms-display-datetimeoffset-value-in-local-timezone) which shows how to display each column in the timezone, but it's cumbersome if there are multiple columns.

Comment: How many datetimeoffset columns do you have? Would it make more sense to supply views (if the AT TIME ZONE is always the same) or TVFs (if not)? Would it make things easier if you stored UTC instead of datetimeoffset in the first place?

Comment: There are at least three that would be displayed.  Using a view would work, but as I asked, this is for "on a whim" queries for rapid investigation of the data.  And part of the reason for datetimeoffset is so we can receive datetime information from different timezones and do valid moment-in-time comparisons.

Although on receipt via Newtonsoft JSON we could specify DateTimeZoneHandling of Utc vs. the default RoundtripKind, so everything would be stored uniformly...

Food for thought, thanks.

Comment: Even if people are querying "on a whim" they can be trained to use the view instead of the table. If they can't, you can always swap names of things.